# VBA user-defined function to copy value, text formation and hyperlink of a cell?

Tags: excel, copy, user-defined-functions, excel-udf, vba

Given a sample plain excel file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/copy%20excel%20cell%20value%20and%20formation.xlsx), what is the VBA code to copy value, formation and hyperlink of a cell?

i.e. At cell B5 we will call `=myCopyCellFunction(B2)` and we will get the exact cell value at B2

[image]

Comment: you want to copy a cell's value and format or formula? Have you tried recording some code? Please show us the code you're having trouble with

Comment: I don't think you can use a User Defined Function to do anything in Excel other than return value(s).  If I understand your question correctly you want it to insert a hyperlink?  You will have to do this using a macro rather than a UDF (i.e. change your UDF from a Function to a Sub).

Comment: why do you think you need a UDF? Tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and show us your code so we can help

Comment: @Philip THe B2 cell is the content copied from wikipedia with hyperlink and nice text formation. I just want to bring the original cell to another table where I manupilate the wiki data. It would be lovely if Excel have another operator, says `f=`, besiade `=' operator

Comment: @NamG.VU try my answer below

Answer (score 1):

try this in a normal code module

```
Function copyIt(ByVal vRange As Range) As String
Dim sAddress As String
Dim sText As String
'
Application.EnableEvents = False

Application.ThisCell.Hyperlinks.Delete
' handle non hyperlinks in source cell
If vRange.Hyperlinks.Count < 1 Then
    copyIt = vRange.Text
    Exit Function
End If
'
' get values for new hyperlink in target cell
sAddress = vRange.Hyperlinks(1).Address
sText = vRange.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay
'
' apply link to target cell
Application.ThisCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Application.ThisCell, Address:=sAddress, TextToDisplay:=sText
' return string value 
copyIt = sText
'    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Function
```

then you use it in a cell like this:

`=copyIt(B2)`

Comment: I tried yours but not working for me as this sample https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/copy%20excel%20cell%20value%20and%20formation.xlsm